# How to calculate product price based on custom action in Catalog Price Rules

Tags: magento2, discount, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

I have added new action in catalog price rule.

[image]
I have added this action through overriding below file.

> module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Action/SimpleActionOptionsProvider.php

When this action is applied then how to calculate product price based on this action.

**In magento module-catalog-rule which file/function is used to calculate product price when other action is applied.**

Anyone knows then please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been recently fighting with something similar. Take a look at **\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\ProductPriceCalculator** class

```
public function calculate($ruleData, $productData = null)
{
    if ($productData !== null && isset($productData['rule_price'])) {
        $productPrice = $productData['rule_price'];
    } else {
        $productPrice = $ruleData['default_price'];
    }

    switch ($ruleData['action_operator']) {
        case 'to_fixed':
            $productPrice = min($ruleData['action_amount'], $productPrice);
            break;
        case 'to_percent':
            $productPrice = $productPrice * $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100;
            break;
        case 'by_fixed':
            $productPrice = max(0, $productPrice - $ruleData['action_amount']);
            break;
        case 'by_percent':
            $productPrice = $productPrice * (1 - $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100);
            break;
        default:
            $productPrice = 0;
    }

    return $this->priceCurrency->round($productPrice);
}
```

You'd validate your custom value is being received in **$ruleData['action_operator']** and then add a new case with your custom logic

Comment: I have tried this way but its not working.

Comment: That piece of code is fired when saving a product, or reindexing... Maybe you have tried just saving a catalogrule? Because in that case, the code is not fired

Comment: That code is fired after catalogrule is applied and reindexing.

Comment: I believe reindex does not occur when you save & apply a catalog rule (not in the Magento2 versions I have worked with). That just flags catalog rule prices index as invalid, so cron will reindex it next time it executes