# Magento 2 override Catalog Price Rules to be able to increase the price

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

We are trying to extend the Catalog Price Rules to make it possible to increase the price of a small group of products.

We have already tried to adjust the calculation in the file below, but this has no effect at all.

vendor\magento\module-catalog-rule\Helper\Data.php

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Magento does not have a price increment concept for catalog price fules. You can check below solution https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/price-adjustments.html

Comment: I know that and, therefore, I am looking for a way to be able to do it within Catalog Price Rules.

Comment: I think there are quite complex work. You can to changes the pricing concept of   magento.

Comment: First changes the logic of final where Magento takes lowest price between, regular, special and tier and catalog ,. Need to take highest  https://belvg.com/blog/the-functionality-and-basic-concepts-of-price-generation-in-magento-2.html

Comment: I am looking for a solution similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168197/magento-2-custom-action-for-catalog-rule
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255185/how-to-calculate-product-price-based-on-custom-action-in-catalog-price-rules

by adding an action and calculating on which I perform a calculation to raises the price.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you to create a plugin

```
<type name="\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index">
    <plugin name="before-checkout-index" type="\Cpy\Checkout\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Index" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Then in that plugin you can call you helper

Something like that

```
/**
 * @param $subject
 * @param $proceed
 * @return mixed
 */
public function aroundExecute($subject, $proceed)
{
    $errors =  $this->addToCartHelper->checkCart();

    if(is_array($errors)) {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error);
        }
        return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
    } else {
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Where `addToCartHelper` is your custom helper and `checkCart()` the method that will return you all the errors messages depending on your logic

On the helper, you can reach all the items like below

```
public function checkCart()
{
    $errors = [];
    $items = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    // ...

    if(!count($errors)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Only I am looking for a solution within the Catalog Price Rule